# I can't connect the EntityManager to the javaFX

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm using Persistence unit and Entity classes from Database, all in a JavaFx fxml Application, I succeeded importing all my tables as entities in my Model, the proble is that I get an exceptions and errors when I try to insert into an entity, here's my entire code

MAIN:

```
package com.example.systemzarzadzaniahurtownia;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {
   private static EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("thePersistenceUnit");
   private static EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();


   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
      Parent root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Home.fxml"));
      stage.setResizable(false);
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
   }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.doGetMessageLogger(Logger.java:2562)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2530)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.internal.HEMLogging.messageLogger(HEMLogging.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.<clinit>(PersistenceXmlParser.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@5.6.1.Final/org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:50)
    at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at java.persistence@2.2/javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at com.example.systemzarzadzaniamagazynem/com.example.systemzarzadzaniahurtownia.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:467)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:366)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.SQLException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 25 more
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="thePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>Entity.Dostawcy</class>
        <class>Entity.DostawyId</class>
        <class>Entity.Dostawy</class>
        <class>Entity.DostawyId</class>
        <class>Entity.Dostawy</class>
        <class>Entity.Kategorie</class>
        <class>Entity.Klienci</class>
        <class>Entity.Towary</class>
        <class>Entity.Zamowienia</class>
        <class>Entity.ZamWieniaTowaruId</class>
        <class>Entity.ZamWieniaTowaru</class>
        <class>Entity.DostawyId</class>
        <class>Entity.Dostawy</class>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hurtownia" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I have no idea where the error is. Thanks for each answer.

[Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndfoy.png)

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wBoY.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RHTk.png)

Comment: You have missing dependecy in your project

Comment: looks unrelated to javafx - make sure you can connect to the manager in a pure java example (no ui) first. And no screenshots of plain text, please (you already provide the stacktrace as text, no need to add an image as well - it's unreadable, unsearchable, uncopiable anyway :)

Comment: Do i need an entity class to connect to a ready database in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

the jdbc is misssing, you can install the connector first
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: I have a connector added by Maven

Answer (score 0):

Check your `module-info.java` file. There should be a...

```java
requires java.sql;
```

and a...

```java
opens com.example.systemzarzadzaniahurtownia to org.hibernate.orm.core, javafx.fxml;
```